# Does the Stone's Edge feature for the UA Stone Sorcerer work with cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, unearthed-arcana, cantrips

At 14th level, Stone Sorcerers (from [Unearthed Arcana: Sorcerer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/26_UASorcererUA020617s.pdf#page=4)) get the Stone's Edge feature, which states:

> When you cast a spell that deals damage, choose one creature damaged by that spell on the round you cast it.

Does this work with cantrips, or is it exclusive to 'leveled' spells only?
Also, if I use *booming blade* and *thunderous smite* in one attack, does the Stone's Edge ability stack?

Comment: The Stone Sorceror was deprecated with the release of Xanathar’s Guide to Everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, *Stone's Edge* affects Cantrips

If the feature did not affect Cantrips, it would expressly say so.

> Starting at 14th level, your mastery of earth magic allows you to add the force of elemental earth to your spells. When you cast a spell that deals damage, choose one creature damaged by that spell on the round you cast it. That creature takes extra force damage equal to half your sorcerer level. This feature can be used only once per casting of a spell.
>
> —**Stone's Edge**, [Unearthed Arcana: Sorcerer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/26_UASorcererUA020617s.pdf)

## Yes, *Stone's Edge* can affect multiple spells

There's no language stating this damage may only be dealt once per turn, so it must be able to be applied to both spells.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, it works with cantrips

There is no qualifier for the [Stone Sorcerer's Stone's Edge](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/26_UASorcererUA020617s.pdf) so it applies to all spells, both cantrips and level 1+.

### Stacks with Booming Blade

The only limits you have from Stone's Edge are:

> When    you cast    a   spell   that    deals   damage, choose  one creature    damaged by  that    spell   on  the round   you cast    it. That    creature
> takes   extra   force   damage  equal   to  half    your sorcerer   level.  This    feature can be  used    only once   per casting of  a   spell.

In this case, you have cast two spells that affect the same creature. You can apply the Stone's Edge to both.

### But something is weird

It's unclear what "can be used only once per casting of a spell" means. It's likely that this is protect against Quickening a spell to get it twice, but it's something to consider for other combos you may have in mind.

Comment: I believe the "can be used only once per casting of a spell" is very clear about the fact that damaging spells that last longer than a round would not get this bonus on subsequent rounds ... like Witch Bolt would only get the bonus damage on the round it was cast. I mean, an additional precision since it also specifies "on the round you cast it".